# python - csvfile replace column values by NaN when other column equal certain values

Tags: python, csv, nan

Sorry if the title is somehow long and weird...

I have the following csv file:

```
Date,Value1,Value2
01-01-01,01,01
02-01-01,02,00
03-01-01,03,01
04-01-01,04,01
```

In this dataset I would like to replace the data of `Value1` column by a `NaN` when the data of `Value2` column equal `00`.

So the output dataset should look like this:

```
Date,Value1,Value2
01-01-01,01,01
02-01-01,NaN,00
03-01-01,03,01
04-01-01,04,01
```

I tried with the following codes but I am missing some of the conditions and it obviously does not work:

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
data['Value1'][data.Value2 == 00] = np.NaN
```

Does anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Yes i can but it is just not producing what I want! I ll update my question with a piece of my trash try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/your_csv.csv')
df.loc[df['Value2'] == 0,'Value1']=np.nan
```

Output

```
        Date     Value1 Value2
    0   1/1/2001    1.0 1
    1   2/1/2001    NaN 0
    2   3/1/2001    3.0 1
    3   4/1/2001    4.0 1
```